# Running shell commands in .php file from command-line

Tags: php, shell

I have a series of shell commands I want to put in a program and execute the program from the command line. I decided to use PHP for this so currently I am trying to get the most basic shell commands to run.

Save as build.php

```
<?php
shell_exec('cd ..');
echo "php executed\n";
?>
```

From the command-line

```
php build.php
```

Output

```
php executed
```

Php executes correctly but I'm still in the same directory. How do I get shell_exec( ... ) to successfully call a shell command?

Comment: what do you expect with `cd ..` ?

Comment: the script runs its own shell. I don't believe there's a way to get a script to change your shell.

Comment: @AliMasudianPour I expect to go to the parent directory

Comment: You can do it: `shell_exec('ls ../');` just to get the previous directory list. You cant change directory

Comment: Use [`chdir()`](http://www.php.net/chdir) to change the working directory of the PHP script.  The default working directory is ".", that is the current working directory whence the script was run.  You can use [`getcwd()`](http://www.php.net/getcwd) to get the current working directory.  Finally, the PHP script cannot change the directory of the *calling* shell.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to change the `cwd` (current working directory) in PHP... any `cd` command you execute via `exec()` and its sister functions will affect **ONLY** the shell that the exec() call invokes, and anything you do in the shell.

```
<?php
    $olddir = getcwd();
    chdir('/path/to/new/dir');  //change to new dir
    exec('somecommand');
```

will execute `somecommand` in `/path/to/new/dir`. If you do

```
<?php
    exec('cd /path/to/new/dir');
    exec('somecommand');
```

`somecommand` will be executed in whatever directory you started the PHP script from - the `cd` you exec'd just one line ago will have ceased to exist and is essentially a null operation.

Note that if you did something like:

```
<?php
    exec('cd /path/to/new/dir ; somecommand');
```

then your command WOULD be executed in that directory... but again, once that shell exits, the directory change ceases to exist.