# Can't detect 1080p and higher video url from Youtube

Tags: php, curl, youtube

I am trying to make a Youtube video downloader by using this php script. I have got it from here.

https://github.com/jeckman/YouTube-Downloader

It works fine and shows direct link up to 720p resolution to download. But unable to detect URL over 720p even though 4k quality is available.
So if I want to make 1080p, 1440p, 2160p quality available what will I do.

Current script demo

http://loader.neq3.com/

Answer (score 0):

You could utilize a command-line based youtube downloader, like [youtube-dl](https://github.com/rg3/youtube-dl). By default it will download 720p videos, but it seems that there is a new feature that allows for 1080p downloads as well! More information on [downloading 1080p video with youtube-dl here.](https://github.com/rg3/youtube-dl/issues/2165)

To run commands from within PHP take a look at this stack post: [Running shell commands in .php file from command-line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21891020/running-shell-commands-in-php-file-from-command-line)

Let me know if you need any help!